# How to balance two squares on a see saw in matter.js?

Tags: javascript, matter.js

I have two boxes sitting on a rectangle that I want to balance on a 2D rectangle that acts like a see-saw.

```
   World.add(engine.world, [
        Bodies.rectangle(400, 0, 800, 50, { isStatic: true }),
        Bodies.rectangle(400, 600, 800, 50, { isStatic: true }),
        Bodies.rectangle(800, 300, 50, 600, { isStatic: true }),
        Bodies.rectangle(0, 300, 50, 600, { isStatic: true })
    ]);

    var boxA = Bodies.rectangle(283.6, 480, 80, 80, { density: 0.005 });
    var boxB = Bodies.rectangle(520, 480, 80, 80, { density: 0.005});

    var arrow = Vertices.fromPath('40 0 40 20 100 20 100 80 40 80 40 100 0 50'),
        chevron = Vertices.fromPath('100 0 75 50 100 100 25 100 0 50 25 0'),
        star = Vertices.fromPath('50 0 63 38 100 38 69 59 82 100 50 75 18 100 31 59 0 38 37 38'),
        horseShoe = Vertices.fromPath('35 7 19 17 14 38 14 58 25 79 45 85 65 84 65 66 46 67 34 59 30 44 33 29 45 23 66 23 66 7 53 7');
        var catapult = Bodies.rectangle(400, 520, 320, 20, { friction: 0.5, collisionFilter: { group: group } });


    var group = Body.nextGroup(true);
World.add(engine.world, [
    catapult,
    boxA,
    boxB,
    Bodies.rectangle(400, 600, 800, 50.5, { isStatic: true }),
    Constraint.create({ 
        bodyA: catapult, 
        pointB: Vector.clone(catapult.position),
        stiffness: 1,
        length: 0
    })
]);
```

I adapted it from http://brm.io/matter-js/demo/#catapult and removed a lot of the objects I felt weren't necessary.

I would like to get the objects to balance perfectly, but the issue is the boxes seem to always be sliding. How can I make it so that when the boxes are equal weights that they can balance perfectly, and if I adjust the weight of one side, the see-saw can lean towards the other weight, but not slide off the see-saw? I would prefer if the see-saw weren't overly sensitive to the weight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the real world of physics, a perfectly balanced see-saw is very unstable and sensitive to the weights of the boxes.  A see-saw can balance because of friction between the plank and its pivot.

Add some friction to the pivot to help it stay balanced and some to the boxes to help them stop sliding.

Comment: I need more detail. I attempted to add friction to the boxes and it didn’t work. The boxes appear to still slide off, will update my OP, though friction alone could not do it. I would prefer both boxes when stacked would just not cause shifting.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a composite body on both sides to avoid slipping from the seesaw base.
please see the attached screenshot

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nj3BO.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).